# Can we create a namespace in Enterprise Edition? How can we create a tab for Lightning App?

Tags: managed-package, lightning-aura-components, namespace

I have two basic questions.

Can we create namespace in Enterprise Edition? I need to develop Lightning components.

As far as I know namespace are tied to managed package, and it can be created in Developer Edition. Is that my understanding is correct?

I am able to create tab for a Lightning Component in my Developer Edition. How do I create a tab for a Lightning app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Namespaces are tied to developer edition orgs, that's correct. I think you can currently only create tabs for components, not apps.

Comment: Lightning Tabs can only be wired to components that implement the force:appHostable interface (implements="force:appHostable" in the component's definition). There are no plans to support using a lighting app as a tab - apps are for net new properties not extensions of apps like S1.